# Silverlight file download for COM Interop

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, excel, com

Is the following possible in Silverlight when a button is clicked?

- An Excel template is downloaded from
  a remote server and saved to the local machine
- An instance of the
  template is then opened on the client
- A macro is then executed within the
  new Excel document

I can do everything apart from saving the template to the local machine. I can save this in isolated storage but then I don’t know where this is when trying to open it from the Excel COM interop code. Has anyone any ideas or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [SaveFileDialog](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-SaveFileDialog-in-Silverlight-3.aspx) which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.savefiledialog(VS.95).aspx) to get the file to be saved outside of isolated storage. It doesn't help with the excel part, and there is no way to get directory information on a file being saved or opened on the client side in Silverlight, so I have no easy idea on the rest.

(The hard way is a client side COM Interop Application which defeats the purpose of using Silverlight for this)